# How to rewrite complex mysql_* SELECT as PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm upgrading all my mysql_* to PDO. I can handle simple SELECTs and INSERTs. But I have one complex SELECT using nested loops that I am making a dog's dinner of. I'll post the mysql_* code, which outputs a two-column table with **total registrations at A1 level** in the first column and **total registrations at A1 level *who have paid*** in brackets in the second column.

```
-------------------------
Smithsville : A1 |      |
  10             | (7)  |
-------------------------
Grange : A1      |      |
   4             |  (4) |
-------------------------
Beau Ridge : A1  |      |
   23            |  (16)|
-------------------------
Jonesboro : A1   |      |
   9             | (9)  |
-------------------------
Lexing : A1      |      |
  3              | (1)  |
-------------------------
```

In the full application further tables are genertated across the page for the other levels.

```
$levels = array('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2');

$centres = array('Smithsville', 'Grange', 'Plateau Ridge', 'Jonesboro', 'Lexing');

for ($j = 0; $j < 1; $j++)  /* Does not loop; selects only A1 in queries below*/
    {
       for ($k=0; $k<5; $k++) /* Cycles through the centres */
         {
        $show_count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(Centre) 
                                          FROM exam 
                    WHERE exam.Centre='".$centres[$k]."' 
                    AND exam.Level='".$levels[$j]."'");

        $show_paid = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(Centre) 
                       FROM exam
                       JOIN personal 
                       ON exam.P_ID=personal.P_ID
                       WHERE personal.Paid='1' 
                       AND exam.Centre='".$centres[$k]."'
                       AND exam.Level='".$levels[$j]."'");


    $result_rows = mysql_num_rows($show_count);

    $result_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($show_paid);

        if ($result_rows == 0) 
           { echo 'No registrations';}

              if ($result_rows2 == 0) 
           { echo 'No payments';}


        echo '<table class="Font3White">
            <tr class="Title">
              <td class="width8">'.$centres[$k].' : '.$levels[$j].'</td>
            <tr>';
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($show_count)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($show_paid)))
          { 
             foreach ($row as $key => $value)  
            {
              echo '<td>';
              echo $value;  
                   echo '</td>';
            }

             foreach ($row2 as $key2 => $value2)
            {
                   echo '<td> (';
              echo $value2;  
              echo ')</td>';
            }

             echo '</tr>';
              }
        echo '</table>';
            }

        }
```

My PDO attempt is

```
    for ($j = 0; $j < 1; $j++)  /* Does not loop; selects only A1 */
            {
                        for ($k=0; $k<5; $k++) /* Cycles through the centres */
                    {

            /*//////////////////////////*/
            /*   Prepares statements    */
            /*//////////////////////////*/

        $stmt1 = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(Centre) 
                FROM exam 
                WHERE exam.Centre=:centre   
                AND exam.Level=:level");

        $stmt2 = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(Centre) 
                FROM exam
                JOIN personal 
                ON exam.P_ID=personal.P_ID
                     WHERE personal.Paid='1' 
                AND exam.Centre=:centre 
                AND exam.Level=:level");

        /*/////////////////////*/
        /*   Binds parameters  */
        /*/////////////////////*/

    $stmt1->bindParam(':centre', $centre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':level', $level, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt2->bindParam(':centre', $centre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':level', $level, PDO::PARAM_STR);



    /*//////////////////////////*/
    /*   Executes statements    */
    /*//////////////////////////*/

    $stmt1->execute(array($centre, $level));
    $stmt2->execute(array($centre, $level));


    echo '<table class="Font3White">
            <tr class="Title">
              <td class="width8">'.$centres[$k].' > '.$levels[$j].'</td>
            <tr>';
   while (($row = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) && ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
        { 
           foreach ($row as $key => $value)  
                {
                  echo '<td>';
                  echo $value;  
                       echo '</td>';
                }

                 foreach ($row2 as $key2 => $value2)
                {
                       echo '<td> (';
                  echo $value2;  
                  echo ')</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo '</table>';
        }

    }
```

I know this is terrible but I hope it can be worked with.

Comment: `$stmt1->execute(array($centre, $level);
    $stmt2->execute(array($centre, $level);` you miss in each line one parenthesis here.

Comment: those two queries CAN be executed as a single one. `select count(center), sum(paid=1) etc...`

Comment: Thanks! I added brackets but still doesn't work.

Comment: 1. What manual you are using as a source of PDO examples? 2. Did you try one simple query, just as exercise?

Comment: I'm using http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers and Jason Gilmore's PHP MYSQL book. Covers PDO a bit. And I have got simple SELECTs etc to work. This one is messy.

Comment: 1. Can you show us how you set $centre and $level variables? 2. Execute does not need parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's wrong to make you the dirty work, but that's it.

I made some changes to your code, so **compare** mine with yours.

Hope it helps you.

```
$levels = array('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2');

$centres = array('Smithsville', 'Grange', 'Plateau Ridge', 'Jonesboro', 'Lexing');

foreach ($levels as $level) {
    foreach ($centres as $centre) {

        // As you said, PREPARE
        $stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(Centre) 
                FROM exam 
                WHERE exam.Centre=:centre   
                AND exam.Level=:level");

        $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(Centre) 
                FROM exam
                JOIN personal 
                ON exam.P_ID=personal.P_ID
                     WHERE personal.Paid='1' 
                AND exam.Centre=:centre 
                AND exam.Level=:level");

        $stmt1->bindParam(':centre', $centre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':level', $level, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt2->bindParam(':centre', $centre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':level', $level, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        //You don't need to pass parameters here just on PDOStatement::bindParam
        $stmt1->execute();
        $stmt2->execute();

        echo '<table class="Font3White">
            <tr class="Title">
              <td class="width8">' . $centre . ' > ' . $level . '</td>
            <tr>';

        // Fetch stuffs
        $row = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Don't use while with PDOStatement::fetch, use fetchAll then foreach it.
        if ($row && $row2) {

            foreach ($row as $key /* <= Do you need it? */ => $value) {
                echo '<td>';
                echo $value;
                echo '</td>';
            }

            foreach ($row2 as $key2 /*  <= Do you need it? */ => $value2) {
                echo '<td> (';
                echo $value2;
                echo ')</td>';
            }

            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks so much. At the moment all the values are 0 even though I hooked it up to the live database. A few tweaks and it should be displaying correct data.

Comment: Or maybe I'm being a bit optimistic! The sample data I supplied was a bit simplified; currently there are 15 centres so combining the $levels and $centres won't work.

Comment: Thanks again! You're great. Now the data is displaying. It's looping too much at the moment. My original had a complex 4-column layout and I cannibalised the code a bit for the purposes of my question. So I need to put it all together again with your PDO code and debug for brackets, maybe. I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Got it working! Is it possible to display  different amounts of data for each level without writing separate code blocks for each level? For example, I have 15 centres in the array `$centres`, but not all these centres are in use at each level. Level A1 might require all 15, but A2 only uses 11, B1 13 etc. Currently, all 15 centres display for each level, with 0 displaying for centres not in use. But this might mislead people into thinking that these centres are all in use at each level, and that there is no demand. I would prefer if unused centres did not appear at all on the web page.

Comment: In this way make some associative array => http://pastebin.com/P3wY0PVQ or make a check for 0 centres.

Comment: You mean like a nested array? Should I access subarrays then and replace foreach ($levels as $level) 
   {

Comment: In that case would be `foreach($levels as $level)` and then  `foreach($level as $centre)`

Comment: Sorry, I tried that but it's not working. I followed the syntax for the nested array declaration you gave on pastebin, and I kept the $levels array as it was. I've tried a couple of different variants of the loops. Still nested foreach loops, right? Should I start a new question for this specific problem, and give more complete code fragments? Thanks.

Comment: The new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484681/loop-through-nested-array-to-generate-tables-of-different-lengths . Thanks.

Comment: I posted the code that finally worked over on the chat page you started.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you show us how you set $centre and $level variables? Maybe they are arrays, not strings? If they are - you may have to create new variable and assign value from array to it. Like this:

   `$value_to_bind = $centres[$k];`
2. Execute does not need parameters if you used bindParam() before.
3. I never tried to run 2 queries with same parameter names and same variables binded to them. Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: 1. I think there's a problem there alright. In the mysql_* I get values from the arrays in the form $centres[$k] and $levels[$j]. But I don't know how to get and pass array positions in PDO

Comment: @user2304574 just create new variable inside loop and assign value to it. Like this: `$value_to_bind = $centres[$k]`